# Looking for Flynn's taxonomy code example for OpenMP and MPI

Tags: python, c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

Looking for all Flynn's Taxonomy example code for C/C++ or Python code for understanding

Any code can, I just want to learn something. I try to find some of them but no result.

```
SIMD
SISD
MISD
MIMD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Looking for all Flynn's Taxonomy example code for C/C++ or Python code
> for understanding

The Taxonomy is more about computer architecture *per* se.

Let us start SIMD, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) one can read:

> Single instruction, multiple data (SIMD) is a class of parallel
> computers in Flynn's taxonomy.It describes
> computers with multiple processing elements that perform the same
> operation on multiple data points simultaneously. Such machines
> exploit data level parallelism, but not concurrency: there are
> simultaneous (parallel) computations, but only a single process
> (instruction) at a given moment.

in OpenMP you can use the [SIMD](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu42.html) directive, namely:

```
#pragma omp simd
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    a[i] = b[i] * c[i];
```

Regarding SISD, from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SISD) one can read:

> In computing, SISD (single instruction stream, single data stream) is
> a computer architecture in which a single uni-core processor executes
> a single instruction stream, to operate on data stored in a single
> memory.

This is not *such much* about the code but rather how it will be executed in the underlying architecture. A code that reflect this concept would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   a[i]++;
```

Regarding MISD, from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISD) one can read:

> In computing, MISD (multiple instruction, single data) is a type of
> parallel computing architecture where many functional units perform
> different operations on the same data. Pipeline architectures belong
> to this type, though a purist might say that the data is different
> after processing by each stage in the pipeline.

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   a[i] = 10 * a[i] + a[i] / 2;
```

Regarding MIMD, from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMD) one can read:

> In computing, MIMD (multiple instruction, multiple data) is a
> technique employed to achieve parallelism. Machines using MIMD have a
> number of processors that function asynchronously and independently.

For this you could have a MPI application with two processes where each processes executes two different applications.